# How to get length of array of geometry_msg:Points in service handle?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, services, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to find the length of an array of geometry_msg:Point passed to a service handle, so I can iterate over each Point, apply a transform and then push onto a response. when I use sizeof(req.points) - I get "24"  regardless of the number of points actually in the message.

TransformPoints.srv

```
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
---
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
```

The callback:

```
static bool pointsCallback(image_transform::TransformPoints::Request &req,
                           image_transform::TransformPoints::Response &res) {

      int no_points = sizeof(req.points);
      int point_size = sizeof(geometry_msgs::Point);
      std::cout << no_points << std::endl;
      std::cout << point_size << std::endl;
      std::cout << req.points[0] << std::endl;
      std::cout << req.points[1] << std::endl;
```

Will output something like this:

```
24   # sizeof(req.points)
24   # sizeof(geometry_msgs::Point);
x: 0
y: 1
z: 0

x: 1
y: 2
z: 0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358825/how-to-get-length-of-array-of-geometry_msg:points-in-service-handle?/) by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2020-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @LukeAI,

What you want is not [sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) that returns the size in bytes of the object but [size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) function that returns the size of the vector. So in your case, since the `points` msgs instances are std vectors, it would be something like:

```
auto req_size = req.points.size();
```

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-06**:
I would perhaps even suggest using a [range-based for-loop](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) instead.

**Comment by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on 2020-08-06**:
Weasfas answered my question, as stated. but using the range-based for-loop is what I *really* wanted. I didn't realise the an array in a msg or srv was a std vector.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-06**:
http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields